# ui:inputDate disable is not working suddenly

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Few days ago disable functionality ui: inputDate from controller working, now it is not working and i did not modified any thing.

```
component.find('Due_Date').set("v.disabled","true");
```

Comment: Can you provide more details on what "not working" means above - errors/exceptions being thrown (please check the javascript console)? Appears to do nothing?

Comment: @Dough: no exception showing in java script console and i can able to select the date.